# mysql copy file between different version of InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I got two MySql instances (A and B) running with InnoDB storage engine. I want to perform a backup from A and B. What I am trying to do is copy data file directly from A to B. Will there be any conflict on B after startup? To put it in another way: are the file format of different versions of InnoDB compatible?

Comment: Any specific reasons to not utilize [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:  The copy will give you grief.

Long Answer:

You *cannot* copy just the `.ibd` file; there is important information in `ibdata1`.  This applies even within the same version.

You *may* be able to copy `ibdata1` *and* the `.frm` and `.ibd`, but I would not trust it.  This applies even within the same version.

Copying from a newer version to an older is likely to fail due to new features.

From older to newer -- still risky.